# HTTP Request Smuggling Exploit - Need Clarification on Behavior of the 'Host' Header

Tags: http, http2, request-smuggling

I've been reading about HTTP Request Smuggling attacks and I've come across a situation that I don't fully understand. I've been studying the report by James Kettle where he describes an attack against Netflix's servers (https://portswigger.net/research/http2).

In his report, he explains how he manipulated the 'Content-Length' and 'Transfer-Encoding' headers to smuggle an HTTP request to the backend server, which treated it as two separate requests. He then added an arbitrary prefix to the next request, regardless of who sent it.

The part I don't fully understand is related to the 'Host' header in his injected request:

```
GET /n HTTP/1.1
Host: 02.rs?x.netflix.com
Foo: bar
```

Interestingly, the author of the column informed that Netflix's server responded as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: https://02.rs?x.netflix.com/n
```

However, when I tested the same request on my personal server, I received a different response:

```
nc localhost 8080
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 02.rs?x.netflix.com

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Connection: close
```

My question is, why did the Netflix server respond with a 302 redirection to the '02.rs' domain instead of throwing a 400 error (Bad Request) or simply ignoring the 'Host' header? In my understanding, most web servers would throw an error or ignore the request if they receive a 'Host' header that doesn't match a valid host they are configured to handle.

Any clarification on this matter would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: *"In my understanding, most web servers would throw an error or ignore the request if they receive a 'Host' header that doesn't match a valid host they are configured to handle."* - "most" is not "all". And this one obviously not.